# Can not find libraries in C code

Tags: python, c, cython, cythonize

I am trying to compile a module using cython, but the compiler can not find include libraries in an external c file (I use `cmath` as example, but other libraries that I want such as `cstdio`, `cstdint`, `cstring` have the same issue)

A minimal example is composed of the following 4 simple files:

cfile.c:

```
#include <cmath>
```

test_pxd.pxd:

```
cdef extern from "cfile.c":
    pass
```

test.pyx:

```
cimport test_pxd
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import Extension, setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

sources = ['test.pyx']

extension = [Extension('test',sources)]

setup(ext_modules=cythonize(extension,force=True))
```

If I run the `setup.py` with:

```
 python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

I get the error:

> cfile.c:1:17: fatal error: cmath: No such file or directory

It should be noted that just compiling the c file directly, eg with `g++ -c cfile.c`, does not require any extra linking for the compiler to find these libraries.

How can I make the compiler in cython find the `cmath` (and other, such as `cstdio`, `cstdint`, `cstring`) libraries in an external c file?

Comment: if it is c the name would be `math.h`, `cmath` is the c++ notation

Comment: Also, use a C compiler, e.g. `gcc`, instead of a C++ compiler (`g++` here).

Comment: I tried adding the flag "language='c++' to cythonize, and # distutils: language=c++ to the beginning of every file, but <cmath> still does not work.

Comment: well ok I also had to change the extension to .cpp, not .c, and now it works

Answer (score 0):

The definition should be against the header, not the implementation:

```
cdef extern from "cfile.h":
    pass
```

If using C++ libraries, must add `language='c++'` directive to setuptools/cythonize.

```
cythonize(<..>,
          language="c++",
      )
```

See also [docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html).